# I can't send access_token ( cookie ) to my API

Tags: cookies, server, axios, client

So I have A,B,C. A - client, B - authentication server, C - main server. Everything has SSL certificates installed so https is used as a protocol in all A, B and C.

EDIT: All A, B, C have different hostnames.

The process is this, I make a registration request from A to B and I receive cookies ( access_token ) from B. After this, I make request to C for some information,but I have a middleware on C that checks if the access_token is valid, and it never find the access_token because the cookies are not sent. So A doesn't send the cookies received from B, to C.

Strangely enough, I can send the cookies from A to B again, because the B checks the cookies to see if the user is still logged in.

I try doing this with axios and withCredential: true but still doesn't work.

Here is the request:

```
      await axios
        .post(
          `${url}`,
          {body},
          { withCredentials: true }
         )
```

Here is how the cookies are sent from B:

```
        res.cookie("access_token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            maxAge: 86400000,
            sameSite: "none"
        });
```

I tried almost everything I saw on forums/posts etc... I have almost 10 hours looking into this.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are B and C on the same hostname? is A also on that hostname?

Comment: No, A, B and C are not on the same hostname. They all have different domains @TZHX

Comment: then how do you expect a cookie set in response to a request to B for example to end up sent in a request to C? especially when you're setting it to httponly so it can't be modified by the client.

Comment: Have you configured CORS properly? do debug the traffic in a tool like https://www.getfiddler.com/  and lastly, what is the SAMESITE attributes on the cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not possible the way I tried to, I ended up making B and C having the same domain to solve it.